# VS2013 Auto Format can't handle braceless indents

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, autoformatting

C++ Auto format in VS2013 seems to work fairly well. However, it stumbles when you omit braces. If I type:

```
if (a)
   if(
```

On entering the left paren, auto complete kicks in and I get:

```
if (a)
if ()
```

Does anyone know how to disable this particular auto-format? Or better, is there a fix?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me, is it possible that the `if (a)` line is already indented incorrectly?

Comment: Correction - it does this for me, but only if the `if (a)` line is not indented at all. I can't immediately think of when you would `if` have statements that are not inside something else, and so would be indented. Is that the case in your code? Can you show some surrounding code?

Comment: Gotta ask. That `if (a)` line does *not* tail with a semi-colon or closing brace, *right* ?

Comment: @The Dark the `if (a)` line is indented for me, not sure why you aren't seeing it with an indent. @WhozCraig No semi-colon or closing brace.